# .net - How to restrict a block of code to only 200 threads at a time using semaphoreslim

Tags: .net-core, concurrency, parallel-processing, semaphore

I have developed a .net core Web API and there is a scenario where I have a list of around 1000 records where each record will be looped through and calls a third party api. There is a restriction with the third party API where concurrently only 200 requests can be sent. So, I have used SemaphoreSlim and restricted the number of threads that uses this code block to 200 and it works fine.

When multiple users or multiple requests come in for this endpoint, then the third party api is throwing an error.

How can I restrict the SemaphoreSlim to use only 200 threads across all the requests (when multiple users or requests come in at the same time)?

```
SemaphoreSlim _concurrencySemaphoreForDescartesCall = new SemaphoreSlim(1,200);
    
    List<Task<searchDetailsViewModel>> searchList = new List<Task<searchDetailsViewModel>>(searchCriteriaList.Count);
        foreach (var criteria in searchCriteriaList)
        {
            await _concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();
            searchList.Add(Task.Run<searchDetailsViewModel>(async () =>
            {
                searchDetailsViewModel searchResults = new searchDetailsViewModel();
                try
                {
                    searchResults.searchResults = await AsncCall(criteria);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    searchResults.ErrorMessage = "There was a problem performing the s search.";
                }
                finally
                {
                    // here we release the throttler immediately
                    _concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                }
        
                return searchResults;
            }, cancellationToken));
        }
        
        searchDetailsViewModel[] searchResultsList = await Task.WhenAll(searchList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I restrict the SemaphoreSlim to use only 200 threads across all the requests (when multiple users or requests come in at the same time)?

Change the scope of your `SemaphoreSlim` instance.

Currently, the code creates a `SemaphoreSlim` for each request, so each request is limited to 200 simultaneous requests. To have a `SemaphoreSlim` work across multiple requests, you should define it as shared between those requests. Either encapsulate the `SemaphoreSlim` within a type that is injected with singleton lifetime, or declare the `SemaphoreSlim` as `static`.